# Ajax does not pass POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a form and I need to POST data to a compute.php file.
I have to pass the content of two select fields, named select_1 and select_2.
My fiire button has a onclick='go()' call.

My script code is as follows:

```
function go() {
var sel_1 = document.getElementById('select_1').value;
var sel_2 = document.getElementById('select_2').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "compute.php",
    data: "select_1=" + sel_1 + "&select_2=" + sel_2,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data,status)
      /* ------------ for debug I have an alert with a response ---- */
      {
        alert("passed data are: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      },
    error: function(data,status)
      {
        alert("passed data are: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

On the php side my compute.php file has code as follows:

```
$selection_1 = $_POST["select_1"];
$selection_2 = $_POST["select_2"];

$sqladd = "INSERT INTO table SET column_1 = '$selection_1', column_2 = '$selection_2';";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqladd)) {
   $resultadd= mysqli_query($conn, $sqladd);
   // ------- then for debug purpose
   echo "inserted row with col_1 --->" . $selection_1 . "<--- and col_2 --->" . $selection_2;
} else {
   // ------- either, still for debug purpose
   echo "not inserted. ";
   echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Now the alert box shows that js has correctly got the values of the two select fields, and I also get back a success status, but **my debug echo from compute.php shows empty values for selection_1 and selection_2**, and the table row is inserted but **in the inserted row the table columns are empty**. Apache log shows two notices: *PHP Notice:  Undefined index: select_1 in compute.php* and *PHP Notice:  Undefined index: select_2 in compute.php*. So PHP doesn't receives the two POST values. What am I doing wrong? I have the following rules and conditions in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Can they block POST? If yes, how can I get the same result without blocking POST? I need externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo and to internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php.

Comment: I would suggest instead of embedding your parameters in the SQL, use prepared statements using ? and get mysql to insert the parameters for you, see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: it's among the refining things to do later, but the matter remains that php does not receives those post data from ajax.

Comment: have you tried creating HTML form elements in the page with the post method and tried submitting it that way?

Comment: Tried now in HTML as per your request. Hmmmm..., same result, data are not passing. But checked also with js and form is valid and variables in source page are filled. Bad puzzle :(

Comment: Add some echo's to your PHP so you can verify if its getting to the server at all ?

Comment: If you can use the GET method, then try using the browser url to submit data to the server, start with your http://localhost[:port]/compute.php?select_1=....

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your go function to be like this:

```
function go() {
var sel_1 = document.getElementById('select_1').value;
var sel_2 = document.getElementById('select_2').value;
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "compute.php", 
    data: {"select_1":sel_1 , "select_2":sel_2},
    success: function(data,status)
      /* ------------ for debug I have an alert with a response ---- */
      {
        alert("passed data are: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      },
    error: function(data,status)
      {
        alert("passed data are: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you are receiving POST at all?

Comment: Now checked with code: if (isset($_POST['select_1'])) {
 echo "received select_1.";
} else {
 echo "NOT received select_1 ";
} and got NOT :(

Comment: Are you somehow using a redirection method?

Comment: Did you try to do an actual html form submission?

Comment: Yes just now, and same negative result. Where could I investigate?

Comment: Can you receive a GET request?

Comment: Just to be sure. From phi.ini: `;enable_post_data_reading = Off` , as you see this line is commented out, so clearly $_POST is possible. And `post_max_size = 8M`

Comment: Also tried adding at the top of compute.php: `if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
 $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` . But nothing changed 
}

Comment: can you upload your code on any cloud drive so I can test it against my environment?

Comment: Tried also with `method='get'` in the form, and `$selection_1 = $_GET["select_1"];` in the destination file, but still nothing passes :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function go() {
var sel_1 = $('#select_1').val();
var sel_2 = $('#select_2').val();
$.post("compute.php", {
    select_1 : sel_1,
    select_2 : sel_2
    }, function (answ) {
    console.log(answ);
  });
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Same result, no POST values arrive to compute.php :(

Comment: maybe anything related to data-type? or what else?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Modify your data object in ajax of go function
data: {"select_1": sel_1, "select_2": sel_2}

Answer (score 0):

Your select box must lock like that

```
<select id="select_1">
<option></option></select>
</select>
```

I think your selected boxes are named select_1 and select_2, but you must set the **id** not the name.

p.s if you use the id please paste you html code.

Comment: `echo "<select id='select_1' name='select_1' color='white'>";`   For cross version compatibility I always set both id and name.

Comment: I checked you code and seems to be fine. 
Can you try to submit a simple form (only html and php) and dump the result?

Comment: Tried now in HTML as per your request. Same result, data are not passing. But checked also with js and form is valid and variables in source page are filled.

Comment: As already checked, from phi.ini: `;enable_post_data_reading = Off` , as you see this line is commented out, so clearly $_POST is possible. And `post_max_size = 8M`

Comment: Also tried adding at the top of compute.php: `if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) { $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` . But nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

POST was blocked by .htaccess instructions as above. Changed and now POST is working from html, but still problems in making js/ajax/jquery work for posting my data to compute.php